# Saving networkD3 Sankey diagram using code only

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I've created a Sankey diagram in R, using the `networkD3` package, that I'd like to save as a static image, using code instead of clicking on 'Export' --> 'Save as Image...'.

The current code I've tried (using [this](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/) Sankey diagram as an example) is:

```
library(networkD3)

URL <- paste0(
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
  "master/JSONdata/energy.json")
Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
# Plot
jpeg( filename = "Sankey.jpg", width = 4000, height = 4000)
sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
dev.off()
```

All I'm getting though is a blank white box when I open the image though.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to be straightforward. The answer to this similar question requires code which uses PhantomJS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056733/how-to-capture-html-output-as-png-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest working solution I've found so far is:

1. Install [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). For example using Homebrew for OSX - `brew install phantomjs`
2. Install rbokeh - `install.packages("rbokeh")`

Then:

```
library(rbokeh)
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
          Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
          units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
widget2png(sn, "sankey.png")
```

The result doesn't look great, but this might serve as a starting point for research and improvements.

EDIT: [here's another potential solution](https://rud.is/b/2016/03/04/capturing-wild-widgets-with-webshot/) using the `webshot` package.

Comment: PhantomJS is now discontinued upstream.

Comment: I faced problem in using `rbokeh`. Here is another [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158327/how-can-i-save-a-networkd3sankeynetwork-into-a-static-image-automatically-vi#65159713) which worked perfectly for me.