# How can I save a networkD3::sankeyNetwork() into a static image automatically via rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, sankey-diagram, networkd3

When I write a report in rmarkdown, all my figures as save automatically under the folder `graphs`. However, as a Sankey diagram is different, it does not save as a picture (.png, etc...) automatically. Is there a workaround for this? (without manually saving each diagram via RStudio Plots panel?)

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846931/saving-networkd3-sankey-diagram-using-code-only) before. But the option from `rbokeh` produces a low quality graphic. I tried to use the second option, but it seems that there is an error in the code, because the function throws `object 'vl' not found`.

As that question is from three years ago, I think that there may be a better solution so far.

Example graphic that I want to save:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Guilherme"
date: "12/5/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      fig.path = "graph/")
```

```{r}
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# Plot
sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
             Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
             units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```
````

Comment: is there a way to save as PDF rather than a PNG?

Answer (score 7):

What about something like this:

````
--
title: "sankey as image"
author: "..."
date: "12/5/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
                      fig.path = "graph/")
```

```{r, fig.align='center'}
library(networkD3)
URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

# Plot
sn <- sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
             Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
             units = 'TWh', fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)

# you save it as an html
saveNetwork(sn, "sn.html")

library(webshot)
# you convert it as png
webshot("sn.html","sn.png", vwidth = 1000, vheight = 900)
```
````

Comment: I was messing with webshot, but couldn't figure it out. I didn't know about the `saveNetwork()` function, so that was good to learn.

Comment: It returns the following error to me: 
`TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.`
`TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.`
And the screenshot is not taken

Comment: I reinstall the `phantomjs` package and it works right now

Comment: Same error, and after installing phantomjs.